# How to press right shift in java?

Tags: java, keyevent, awtrobot

My program can't press right shift. 
I  try to use java robot for this, but my method feintOne() only twice press left shift.
At the same time, the program can determine which of the Shift was pressed 
Please help my to investigate.
maybe you will tell my how to refactore this code
or find another solution

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final NativeKeyEvent PRESS_LSHIFT = new NativeKeyEvent(NativeKeyEvent.NATIVE_KEY_PRESSED, 0, 161, NativeKeyEvent.VC_SHIFT,
            NativeKeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED, NativeKeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT);

    private static final NativeKeyEvent RELEASE_LSHIFT = new NativeKeyEvent(NativeKeyEvent.NATIVE_KEY_RELEASED, 0, 161, NativeKeyEvent.VC_SHIFT,
            NativeKeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED, NativeKeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT);

    private static final NativeKeyEvent PRESS_RSHIFT = new NativeKeyEvent(NativeKeyEvent.NATIVE_KEY_PRESSED, 0, 162, NativeKeyEvent.VC_SHIFT,
            NativeKeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED, NativeKeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT);

    private static final NativeKeyEvent RELEASE_RSHIFT = new NativeKeyEvent(NativeKeyEvent.NATIVE_KEY_RELEASED, 0, 162, NativeKeyEvent.VC_SHIFT,
            NativeKeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED, NativeKeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT);

    private static final NativeKeyEvent PRESS_Q = new NativeKeyEvent(NativeKeyEvent.NATIVE_KEY_PRESSED, 0, 81, NativeKeyEvent.VC_Q,
            (char) NativeKeyEvent.VC_Q, NativeKeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN);

    private static final NativeKeyEvent RELEASE_Q = new NativeKeyEvent(NativeKeyEvent.NATIVE_KEY_RELEASED, 0, 81, NativeKeyEvent.VC_Q,
            (char) NativeKeyEvent.VC_Q, NativeKeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN);

    public MyFrame(String Cap) {

        super(Cap);

        setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setVisible(true);

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {

                switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {
                    case (KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT):
                        if (evt.getKeyLocation() == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT) {
                            System.out.println("Left SHIFT");
                        }
                        else if (evt.getKeyLocation() == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT) {
                            System.out.println("Right SHIFT");
                        }
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_R:
                        System.out.println("R");
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void feintOne() {
        GlobalScreen.postNativeEvent(PRESS_LSHIFT);
        GlobalScreen.postNativeEvent(RELEASE_LSHIFT);
        GlobalScreen.postNativeEvent(PRESS_RSHIFT);
        GlobalScreen.postNativeEvent(RELEASE_RSHIFT);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame("Don't mention it");
        feintOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: but my method feintOne() only twice press left shift. -> what do you mean by that?

Comment: I want this to work like this:
1) press left Shift
2) release Left Shift
3) press Right Shift
4) release Right Shift

but it works differently

p.s. sorry for my English

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't answer my question. What about your code does, and what about your code doesn't work?

Comment: can't press right shift in feintOne() method. 

The left shift is pressed instead

Comment: from what library are GlobalScreen and NativeKeyEvent ?

Comment: import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;

Comment: such things are good to know, those aren't exactly standard libraries.

Comment: you're right. added imports to body question's

Comment: add this to your code, and see if it helps you understand a bit:             int counter = 0;
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                counter += 1;
                System.out.println("counter: " + counter + " <--> " + evt.getKeyCode() + " -- " + evt.getKeyLocation());
                System.out.println("Left: " + KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT
                        + " - Right: " + KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT );
                System.out.println("KeyEvents: " + KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT + " - " + KeyEvent.VK_R);

Comment: To be honest, it didn't help. I see, if method feintOne() execute, method GlobalScreen.postNativeEvent(PRESS_RSHIFT) used left location. therefore the left shift is pressed. but I still don't understand how to press the right shift